# IP Address Linux Containers

Tags: networking, lxc

Please, i have a problem i try to find a solution since days
i'm a beginner with linux (networking)

In our cluster (10 nodes), we deploy the same image file on each node. So each node has a different ip address.  In each image, there are several LXC containers.
When I deploy the same machine image on multiple nodes, I had the same IP address for containers.

```
Host 1: ip1                                             Host2: ip2   (ip1#ip2)
ip container c1: 10.0.3.109                      ip container c1: 10.0.3.109
ip container c2:  10.0.3.181                     ip container c2:  10.0.3.181
```

Have you an idea please, how can change ip address of containers automatically  ?
As i read, i have to change the mac address....

Thanks a lot.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Each node's containers are in a separate network from each of the other node's containers.

You can specify a new IP address for each container in `/var/lib/lxc/#container's name/config` by setting `lxc.network.ipv4=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.  If you want your containers accessible from outside the host you'll need to setup forwarding and macquerading on the host and use the host's IP from external sources.